# Laravel constrain parameter to value from database

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Hypothetically, imagine this contrived route in a Laravel 7.x app:

```
Route::get('/profile/{username}', function ($username) {
    /* code here */
})->name('profile.username');
```

My objective is the only allow `{username}` values that comes from the database. Let's assume there is a `users` table with the columns `name` and `level` and only those usernames with the `level` of `>5` should show allow this route to happen. Otherwise, we get an HTTP 404. Is there a specific way in Laravel to make this work?

Comment: Yes, you could do it via a middleware. https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/middleware

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a great candidate for explicit route model binding; depending on how you want to configure this.

The docs cover how to get this going; https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#route-model-binding.

Alternatively, middleware could work - `EnsureUsernameExists`:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $username = $this->route('username');
    User::where('username', $username)->where('level', '>', 5)->firstOrFail();
   
    // Or with abort
   abort_unless(User::where('username', $username)->where('level', '>', 5)->exists(), 404);
}
```

Or you could just run the check inside your controller method, using either approach inside of the middleware.

Comment: If I may ask, how would implicit binding work with checking user level?

Comment: My mistake, I missed the `level` requirement. Explicit RMB would be the way to go :)

Comment: Ah I was genuinely curious :)

Comment: I was initally thinking of suggesting a request validator using the `exists` rule like this: `'username' => 'exists:user,name'`, but the level restriction makes your answer the most straightforward one. +1

Comment: Thanks @AugustoMoura - my only criticism to validation rules for this, is that this is not a validation failure. The route is only valid for usernames where the level is greater than 5 - IMO this does not make sense as a validation rule. However OP will know more about the use case and this could be a viable option as a custom validation rule could also be used.